# ID of Jquery-UI-Tab changed, or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need some help...I did the follow:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="tb-1" position=1 href="tabs-1"> A </a></li>
    <li><a id="tb-2" position=2 href="tabs-2"> B </a></li>
    <li><a id="new-tab" position=3 href="new-tab"> + </a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1"> ... some html...</div>
  <div id="tabs-2"> ... some html...</div>
  <div id="new-tab"></div>
</div>
```

So... a have wrote the JS code:

```
$(".tabs").tabs();

$("#new-tab").click( function( event ) {

    // new tab position
    var position = $(this).attr("position"); 

    // change ID of "new-tab" tab to "tb-X"
    $('#new-tab').attr("id", "tb-"+position);  

    // title of current tab
    $("#tb-"+position).html("NEW");

    // add <div> to the new tab 
    $(".tabs").append( "<div id=\"tabs-"+position+"\"></div>");

    // add some html to the tab (not realy the above code)
    $("#tabs-"+position).html( new_data );

    // add new tab to tabs              
    var url = "#tabs-"+(position*1+1);
    $(".tabs").tabs("add", url, "+");

    // insert ID "new-tab" to the added tab
    $('.tabs li a').eq(position).attr("id", "new-tab");

    ... some more stuffs
```

Then, the results seems perfect.. but...

- Clicking in [+] tab, a new tab is added... ok
- Clicking again in [+] (this is the recently added tab) nothing happenings
- Clicking in the [NEW] tab, it create a new tab again! (The [NEW] tab was the old [+] tab)

Inspecting the code, the ID of [+] tab changed to the new value... all seems to be ok.

What is wrong?

I hope my english was clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'r opening with a single-quote (') and closing with a double-quote (") here: `$('#new-tab").attr("id", "tb-"+position);`

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI for this?

Comment: Yes! but the problems seems to be the changed of the ID attr of the tab...

Comment: What would you like your script to do?

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery's example for adding a tab? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: dynamically add a new tab, clicking on the [+] tab...Yes, I have looked... I didn't find any example like that i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an update.

Now that I understand the jQuery tab control, I think this is exactly what you're going for. Cool idea by the way.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/54WZH/5/

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="tabs-1"> A </a></li>
    <li><a href="tabs-2"> B </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $tbs = $(".tabs");
$tbs.tabs().children("ul").append('<li><a id="new-tab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"> + </a></li>');

$("#new-tab").click( function( event ) {

    //Need to remove our Plus button so it doesn't get counted when 
    //calling tabs("add",...)
    $(this).parent().remove();

    //Get the position of the new tab
    var pos = $tbs.find(" > ul > li:last").index() + 2; 

    //Insert the new tab & re-add the Plus button
    $tbs.tabs("add", "#ui-tabs-" + pos, "New").children("ul").append('<li><a id="new-tab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"> + </a></li>');

    //Your dynamic tab content for this tab
    $("#ui-tabs-" + pos).html("Content-" + pos); 

    //Re-add the event for the Plus Button
    $("#new-tab").click(arguments.callee); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the [+] and the [new] tab are in selected mode (highlighted)!" Is this something that is happening and shouldn't or something that's supposed to be happening and isn't? Also, I don't see anything concerning highlighting in your question. The "return false;" statement cancels the navigation request to "new-tab" (which doesn't exist). You may need to call "newLink.click();" (or something to that effect) to switch to the new tab if that is your intent.

Comment: Thanks Brandon... your code is perfect... the problem now is that I have two tabs with selected class of ui-tabs... I will review my code... perhaps I have make other mistakes. Thanks a lot!